# Prove three sides make a triangle from basic assumptions

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I've been working through *The Four Pillars of Geometry* by John Stillwell.  In exercise 2.5.3 he asks,

> How can we be sure that lengths $a,b,c>0$ with $a^2+b^2=c^2$ actually fit together to make a triangle? (*Hint:* Show that $a+b>c$)

**Lemma:** $a+b>c$.  Suppose not that $a+b\leq c$ then $a^2+b^2+2ab\leq c^2$ and $2ab\leq 0$ $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$ a contradiction is reached since $a,b>0$.

---

So my two questions are, (1) is my proof of the hint correct, and (2) how does that hint lead to the statement that $a,b$ and $c$ do in fact form a triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof of your lemma looks correct. To answer (2), you have $a+b>c$. Also, from $a^2+b^2=c^2$, you have $a^2\lt c^2$ and $b^2\lt c^2$, so $a\lt c$ and $b\lt c$ as all lengths are positive. So $a+c\gt b$ and $b+c\gt a$. Since any two lengths are greater than the third, you know that in a Euclidean plane, by the method of [Euclid I.22](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI22.html) that you can construct a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and pointer to an excellent source!

Comment: @Tony, no problem. I used that online version of the _Elements_ quite a bit when I also self-studied some modern geometry.